# R, count the occurrence of a variable like Excel PivotTable

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Wanted to count the occurrence of a variable in a data frame. It’s easy to do in Excel PivotTable and now learning how to do it in R.

```
      v_time visitor
1/2/2018 16:07    Jack
1/3/2018 16:09    Jack
1/3/2018 16:12   David
1/3/2018 16:16    Kate
1/2/2018 16:21   David
1/2/2018 16:32    Jack
1/4/2018 16:33    Kate
1/4/2018 16:55    Jack
```

Excel can make it easily like this:

[image]

I’ve tried some lines but still not getting there.

```
visitor <- c("Jack", "Jack", "David", "Kate", "David", "Jack", "Kate", "Jack")
v_time <- c("1/2/2018 16:07","1/3/2018 16:09","1/3/2018 16:12","1/3/2018 16:16","1/2/2018 16:21","1/2/2018 16:32","1/4/2018 16:33", "1/4/2018 16:55")
df <- data.frame(v_time, visitor)

as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$v_time, "%m/%d/%Y"))

library(plyr)
count(df$visitor, 'v_time')

as.data.frame(table(df$visitor))
```

What’s the way to produce the Excel PivotTable alike output in R? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [marginal total in tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649004/marginal-total-in-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the time component with either regex (preferred way is to convert to `Date` class  with `as.Date`

```
df$v_time <- sub("\\s+.*", "", df$v_time)
```

Or

```
df$v_time <- as.Date(df$v_time, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

and then do the `table`

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df[2:1]))
```

If we need the `sum` on both margins, do with `addmargins`

```
addmargins(table(df[2:1]))
```

---

The reason OP's code is not working is after converting to `Date`, it is not assigned to 'v_time'

Comment: thank you for your help. is it possible to show the sum on columns and rows as well?

Comment: @MarkK  Thanks, updated the post.  Have a good weekend to you as well

Comment: marvelous! Simple, straight forward, highly efficient!

Answer (score 3):

The hardest part is just getting the day component out of the column.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df)[, day := sub(" .*$", "", v_time)], visitor ~ day, fun.aggregate = length)
#> Using 'day' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
#>    visitor 1/2/2018 1/3/2018 1/4/2018
#> 1:   David        1        1        0
#> 2:    Jack        2        1        1
#> 3:    Kate        0        1        1
```